# Multiple instances of same react component passing values to parent component

Tags: reactjs

We have a page that has a tab on the top. Both tabs show same components, except that on one tab some of the labels and other controls are different (some are hidden, some appear only on one, etc.) The changes are minimal enough that they don't warrant a different component altogether.

So what I am trying to figure out is how to embed multiple instances of the same child component into a parent, and yet be able to pass values from different instances of the child to the parent.

Here is my parent component for example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child1 from "./Child1";

const Parent1 = () => {
  const changeNameFunc = (childName) => {
    alert(childName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Parent
      <div>
        <Child1 id="1" changeName={changeNameFunc} />
        <Child1 id="2" changeName={changeNameFunc} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent1;
```

And here is my child component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child1 = (props) => {
  const [name, setname] = useState();

  const clicketyclick = () => {
    const newName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    setname(newName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" />
      <button onClick={clicketyclick}>Change Child Name</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.changeName(name)}>Send To Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child1;
```

In this case the problem is obviously in my clicketyclick function because the document.getElementById picks up the first control that matches that ID in the DOM. In my code at work, we aren't picking up values using document.getElement, rather we are passing state object up to the parent via a props.function call.

So to make it random, I changed my child code in this example to following.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child1 = (props) => {
  const [name, setname] = useState();

  function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

  const clicketyclick = () => {
    const newName = getRandomInt(100); // document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    setname(newName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" />
      <button onClick={clicketyclick}>Change Child Name</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.changeName(name)}>Send To Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child1;
```

Now this works just fine. If I click ChangeChildName on first instance of Child control, it sets a random number (say 54) to the state of that instance. If I then click SendToParent on first instance of Child control, it alerts 54. If I click ChangeChildName on *second* instance of Child control, it sets a different random number (say 98) to the state of that instance. If I then click SendToParent on *second* instance of Child control, it alerts 98. This is great. It means the state is owned by the instance of the child control.

So with this knowledge, are there any gotchas with nesting multiple instances of a child component into a parent? Is it better to just avoid it and create a separate component even if 98% of the functionality is same? I've read somewhere that in this case we should make sure different instances have different "id" property (though taking it out didn't make any difference; my code still worked). I've also read somewhere about passing in a context of some sort to prefix the field ids with (not sure how that would work).

What is the best way to do this i.e. have a parent render multiple instances of a child control, and then have each child send their respective data up to the parent without causing any collisions or other gnarly problems with state management.

Edit: My question really isn't about the getElementById part. My question is what is the proper way to have multiple instances of a control embedded inside a parent component. Are you supposed to pass some sort of prefix for the ids in the child control, and if so how? Are you supposed to have an "id" attribute on the child control definition inside the parent control to make react aware of it that they are unique? Or something else?

Comment: I don't really think you should ever use IDs in React and I don't see much of a reason to use name here. Having each child component calling the function passed by their parent is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const Child1 = (props) => {
    const [name, setname] = useState('');
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    const clicketyclick = () => {
        const newName = inputRef.current.value;
        setname(newName);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" ref={inputRef} />
            <button onClick={clicketyclick}>Change Child Name</button>
            <button onClick={() => props.changeName(name)}>
                Send To Parent
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Ok, I just read about useRef and it is not clear to me what you are doing here. What does adding ref={inputRef} that is initialized to null do exactly?

Comment: useRef allows you to directly create a reference to the DOM element, when you pass inputRef to input, it means you can access to input element by inputRef.current. initialized  value of useRef can be anything but if you use ref for access DOM, initialized  value should be null until component  mounted